# How to display a 2d interpolation function in python as a matrix?

Tags: python, matrix, 2d, interpolation

I looked around a lot but it's hard to find an answer. Basically when one interpolates v -> w you would normally use one of the many interpolation functions. But I want to get the corresponding matrix Av = w.

In my case w is a 200x200 matrices with v beeing a random subset of w with half as many points. I don't really care for fancy math it could be as simple as weighting the known points by distance squared. I already tried just implementing it all with some for loops but it only really works with small values. But maybe it helps explaining my question.

```
from random import sample

    def testScatter(xbig, ybig):
        NumberOfPoints = int(xbig * ybig / 2) #half as many points as in full Sample

    #choose random coordinates
    Index = sample(range(xbig * ybig),NumberOfPoints)
    IndexYScatter = np.remainder(Index,  xbig)
    IndexXScatter = np.array((Index - IndexYScatter) / xbig, dtype=int)

    InterpolationMatrix = np.zeros((xbig * ybig , NumberOfPoints), dtype=np.float32)
    WeightingSum = np.zeros(xbig * ybig )
    coordsSamplePoints = []
    for i in range(NumberOfPoints): #first set all the given points (no need to interpolate)
        coordsSamplePoints.append(IndexYScatter[i] + xbig * IndexXScatter[i])
        InterpolationMatrix[coordsSamplePoints[i], i] = 1
        WeightingSum[coordsSamplePoints[i]] = 1
    
    for x in range(xbig * ybig): #now comes the interpolation
        if x not in coordsSamplePoints:
            YIndexInterpol = x % xbig      #xcoord in interpolated matrix
            XIndexInterpol = (x - YIndexInterpol) / xbig  #ycoord in interp. matrix
            for y in range(NumberOfPoints):
                XIndexScatter = IndexXScatter[y]
                YIndexScatter = IndexYScatter[y]
                distanceSquared = (np.float32(YIndexInterpol) - np.float32(YIndexScatter))**2+(np.float32(XIndexInterpol) - np.float32(XIndexScatter))**2
                InterpolationMatrix[x,y] = 1/distanceSquared
                WeightingSum[x] += InterpolationMatrix[x,y]

    return InterpolationMatrix/ WeightingSum[:,None] , IndexXScatter, IndexYScatter
```

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: If anyone knows a way to make it faster or if just made a mistake along the way. I'm quite new to programming, sorry.

Comment: You are confident of the *math* your function implements? When you test the function with a known input does it produce the correct result? Can you explain in words what your function does? What is `sample(range(xbig * ybig),NumberOfPoints)`? -`NameError: name 'sample' is not defined`

Comment: Sorry I added the line where I implemented it. Its from random. It did produce the correct answer when tested on 9x9 matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to spend some time with the Numpy documentation start at the top of [this page](https://numpy.org/doc/1.19/) and working your way down. *Studying* answers here on SO for questions asking how to vectorize an operation when using Numpy array's would help you. If you find that you are iterating over indices and performing calcs with Numpy arrays there is probably a better way.

First cut...
The first for loop can be replaced with:

```
coordsSamplePoints = IndexYScatter + (xbig * IndexXScatter)
InterpolationMatrix[coordsSamplePoints,np.arange(coordsSamplePoints.shape[0])] = 1
WeightingSum[coordsSamplePoints] = 1
```

This mainly makes use of [elementwise arithmetic](https://numpy.org/doc/1.19/user/quickstart.html#basic-operations) and [Index arrays](https://numpy.org/doc/1.19/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays) - the complete Indexing Tutorial should be read

You can test this by enhancing the function and executing the for loop along with *Numpy way* then comparing the result.

```
...
    IM = InterpolationMatrix.copy()
    WS = WeightingSum.copy()
    for i in range(NumberOfPoints): #first set all the given points (no need to interpolate)
        coordsSamplePoints.append(IndexYScatter[i] + xbig * IndexXScatter[i])
        InterpolationMatrix[coordsSamplePoints[i], i] = 1
        WeightingSum[coordsSamplePoints[i]] = 1
    cSS = IndexYScatter + (xbig * IndexXScatter)
    IM[cSS,np.arange(cSS.shape[0])] = 1
    WS[cSS] = 1
    # TEST Validity
    print((cSS == coordsSamplePoints).all(),
          (IM == InterpolationMatrix).all(),
          (WS == WeightingSum).all())
...
```

---

The outer loop:

```
...
    for x in range(xbig * ybig): #now comes the interpolation
        if x not in coordsSamplePoints:
            YIndexInterpol = x % xbig      #xcoord in interpolated matrix
            XIndexInterpol = (x - YIndexInterpol) / xbig  #ycoord in interp. matrix
            ...
```

Can be replaced with:

```
...
    space = np.arange(xbig * ybig)
    mask = ~(space == cSS[:,None]).any(0)
    iP = space[mask]    # points to interpolate
    yIndices = iP % xbig
    xIndices = (iP - yIndices) / xbig
    ...
```

Complete solution:

```
import random
import numpy as np
def testScatter(xbig, ybig):
    NumberOfPoints = int(xbig * ybig / 2) #half as many points as in full Sample

    #choose random coordinates
    Index = random.sample(range(xbig * ybig),NumberOfPoints)
    IndexYScatter = np.remainder(Index,  xbig)
    IndexXScatter = np.array((Index - IndexYScatter) / xbig, dtype=int)
    InterpolationMatrix = np.zeros((xbig * ybig , NumberOfPoints), dtype=np.float32)
    WeightingSum = np.zeros(xbig * ybig )
    
    coordsSamplePoints = IndexYScatter + (xbig * IndexXScatter)
    InterpolationMatrix[coordsSamplePoints,np.arange(coordsSamplePoints.shape[0])] = 1
    WeightingSum[coordsSamplePoints] = 1

    IM = InterpolationMatrix
    cSS = coordsSamplePoints
    WS = WeightingSum

    space = np.arange(xbig * ybig)
    mask = ~(space == cSS[:,None]).any(0)
    iP = space[mask]    # points to interpolate
    yIndices = iP % xbig 
    xIndices = (iP - yIndices) / xbig
    dSquared = ((yIndices[:,None] - IndexYScatter) ** 2) + ((xIndices[:,None] - IndexXScatter) ** 2)
    IM[iP,:] = 1/dSquared
    WS[iP] = IM[iP,:].sum(1)

    return IM / WS[:,None], IndexXScatter, IndexYScatter
```

I'm getting about 200x improvement with this over your original with (100,100) for the arguments. Probably some other minor improvements but they won't effect execution time significantly.

---

[Broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/1.19/user/basics.broadcasting.html) is another Numpy skill that is a *must*.

Comment: Thanks, this looks way cleaner. It doesn't seem to be any faster though. Any ideas on cutting down on speed?

Comment: I only did one of the for loops.

Comment: I implemented it in both loops and now it is 20 times faster. I really appreciate the help and your linked resources. You are a great part of this community!

Comment: @GregorFreund - see my last edit ~200x faster with 100x100.

Comment: Thanks this was very informative. Just one question: What is the difference between e.g. IM[iP,:] and IM[iP]? Is it simply for readability?

Comment: @GregorFreund - nothing really except that `IM[iP , :]` is explicit and sometimes that helps when you are reading something you are unfamiliar with or wrote six months ago.  See the third paragraph in https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#single-element-indexing